# In IntelliJ how to create relative paths to swcs in module dependencies for Flex or actionscript modules?

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea, flexbuilder

Can someone tell me if its possible to create relative as opposed to absolute paths to swcs in module dependencies for Flex or actionscript modules?

In Flex Builder i would simply edit the swc path as

'../lib/.swc

But there doesn't seem to be a way to edit the path in IntelliJ once you've defined it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use a swc that is inside of the module's folder sources? ( one of the tabs next to dependencies ). I have never needed to identify this I assume its because you want your project portable?

If you establish this is by design, make a feature request if you already don't have an account.
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea